log-log regression, possible in Altair?
Is there any way to do a log-log regression (both x and y axes are on a logarithmic scale)? Linear-linear, linear-log, log-linear all seem straightforward.

You should be able to get the required behaviour by defining the y variable that you fit against to be log(y') where y' is your original y value. And then do a lin-log fit on log(x). Beware that log is only defined for positive values.
